# set_global("downlink_cloud", 5) in simmer package in R does not work

Tags: r

So I am still new in running simulation in R using simmer package. So here is my code.

```
library(simmer)
library(simmer.plot)
env <- simmer('offloading')%>%
  add_resource("uplink_fog", capacity) %>%
  add_resource("uplink_cloud", capacity) %>%

    set_global("uplink_cloud", 5) %>%
  add_resource("fog", capacity) %>%
    # set_global("downlink_fog", 10) %>%
    # set_global("downlink_cloud", 5) %>%
  add_resource("cloud", capacity) %>%
  add_resource("downlink", capacity)
```

whey I execute this code, it shows Error in UseMethod("set_global") : 
  no applicable method for 'set_global' applied to an object of class "simmer". I wonder why. When I comment the code set_global, it works well. How can I fix this error?

Comment: [Accodring to the docs](https://r-simmer.org/reference/set_attribute.html), the `set_global` functions expect a "trajectory object" but you don't seem to have a call to `trajectory()` anywhere.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I know what should I do.